# Распечатать этикетку со штрих-кодом. C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, штрихкод

Нужно распечатать этикетку со штрих-кодом. Хочу использовать PrintDialog, но не знаю как сделать разные шрифты у разных участков текста и распечатать штрих-код. Есть мысль распечатать штрих-код используя специальный шрифт вроде этих http://ru.fontriver.com/dingbats/bar_code/ . Вопрос стоит в том как изменить шрифт у кусков выводимого на печать текста или как распечатать этикетку более простым способом.

Сейчас этикетка выводится так:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.AllowPrintToFile = true;

        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DocumentName = "document";
        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PD_PrintPage);

        printDialog.Document = printDocument;
        DialogResult docPrn = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (docPrn.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }

    private void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string PrintText = "Название продукта: " + productsDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value + "\r\n";
        PrintText += "Тип продукта: " + productsDataGridView.SelectedCells[7].Value + "\r\n";
        Font PrintFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 3, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintText, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так ты вызывай `DrawString` несколько раз с разными шрифтами, задавая PointF, который идет следом за предыдущим текстом.